# Why is Edge's InPrivate and Chrome's Incognito disabled?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-10, windows-registry, private-browsing

I checked the other question and please don't mark mine as a duplicate. As I just want to know how can they be disabled if even in the `regedit` there appears no file as `Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\IncognitoModeAvailability`.

I'm currently using Windows 10 and from the past couple of days Incognito has been disabled without no edits in the registry.

I don't even know if I  can enable it by opening the folder in the regedit, but I just want to know how such a thing can happen considering I'm the administrator of this laptop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you on a corporate network?

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ Nope.

Comment: some folks have discussed disabling inprivate for edge here : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/disabling-inprivate-in-edge/22d34dc1-43dd-42a4-b531-6838f960ff4c?auth=1 , so reversing it should enable it back on at least for edge.

Comment: Which question is "The other question"?  If you log in with a different user account, does it behave the same way?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I only logged in with one account and only have one account.

Comment: OK, then make another account, log in with it, and see if it behaves the same way.  If not, you know it's specific to your user account.  It's called troubleshooting, and you'll need to perform some, and then end what you discover into your question, so that your problem can be narrowed down to something that may be answerable. As-is its too broad (in my opinion anyway).